# autocomplete with JSP after select li suggesting the text input lose its selector

Tags: javascript, jsp

I  use  autocomplete box  to suggest some value.
It  works good with me  but  I have this problem after I select value the text input selector orange color is removed

My text input

`<input type="text" size="30" value="" id="inputString" 
onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" onblur="fill();" />`

My JavaScript code

```
function lookup(inputString) {
if(inputString.length == 0) {
$('#suggestions').hide();
} else {
$.post("states.jsp", {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data){
if(data.length >0) {
$('#suggestions').show();
$('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data);
 $('#suggestions li').click(function() {
var vel = $(this).html();
 $('#inputString').val(vel);
});
}
});
}
}







function fill(thisValue) {
$('#inputString').val(thisValue);
setTimeout("$('#suggestions').hide();", 200);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

@user1683781 How you are composing data in states.jsp page? You can add the css in same states.jsp page. Else you can add the css where you filling your data to input.

```
$('#inputString').css({"color":"orange","background-color":"#ccc"});
```

Let me know if this rectify your issue.